# Updating product Tax Class ID

Tags: magento2, product, tax, magento-2.1.9, tax-class

We are trying to get all the products to have the tax Class to Taxable goods. I tried modifying the database in order to change the value to '2'- It did indeed change in the database but even after upgrading database, compiling and deploying and flushing cache it did not change the value. I also did reindex.

The SQL I have used:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_index_price SET tax_class_id = 2;

UPDATE catalog_product_index_price_idx SET tax_class_id = 2;

UPDATE catalog_product_index_price_tmp SET tax_class_id = 2;
```

I basically did the update anywhere I could see the `tax_class_id`;

What I managed to do next is going to:

1. Backend > Catalog > Manage Products > Select all.
2. Going to Top left Actions dropmenu, selected “Update attributes” and submitted.
3. I went to find `Tax Class` and selected `Taxable Goods` and saved.

That managed to change the value in the backend, but still, the frontend appears to not change.

[image]

And the tax class succesfully created:
[image]

You can see there is no change:

[image]